# What information can a source code contain?

Tags: web-application, appsec, source-code

Can an application's source code contain the user name and/or the password?

If yes, How can we determine it?

Also what other information can it contain?

Comment: I would suggest gaining some experience in building applications before attempting to determine security vulnerabilities in them; this question is hopelessly broad as it is.

Comment: Can it? Sure. Programmers can put any hard coded data in their code. Or none at all.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your tag you are talking about web applications. You should not be hard coding user names, passwords or connection strings in your source code.  These should be in config files or in your database depending on your platform and architecture.

You can and should ensure this data is encrypted - .net for example allows encryption of web config files. You should also ensure your web server will not serve config files and protect against attacks that may obtain them eg - directory traversal attacks , padbuster attacks.

That removes anything seriously confidential from source but remember not to leave source back ups in your accessible web directory.

With the source your attacker will have a complete picture of how your application works, how you authenticate, accepted inputs, error handling and everything else about your application. There are an uncountable number of exploits they could determine from this by manually analysing the code or running it through a static analysis tool.

Answer (score 0):

In a properly configured 3 tier app, no password is supposed to be hardcoded to the source code.

Source code is like the blue print of a house. If you have the blueprint you can easily identify all the easy way in and out. Similarly if the source code is available it can be revived to identify vulnerabilities to crack the software. If it is a commercial software people can compile and make there own solution.

Comment: Vulnerabilties, so how  can we determine it? means what info. identifies me that this is vulnerabilty.

Comment: The flow of data is the main thing. We determine how input is coming through and where it ends up. For example if a user input is taken and reflected without passing the data through any proper validation scheme, XSS is possible.

Answer (score 0):

Usernames and password in the source code are bad practices and dangerous. Doesn't matter if your code is publicly available or not, an attacker that discovers those credentials will have access to the application. In most cases hardcoded credentials have special privileges, are hard to change (As it implies changing code, maybe compiling, testing and deploying), can't be locked and sometimes don't use the regular workflow in the application (Like loging!). All those things are undesirable in a web application, it's a backdoor into your application

Other things that are common to find in source code and shouldn't be there are:

- String connections to database
- Hardcoded encryption keys
- Hardcoded testing values (Like `4242424242424242` for credit cards)

In the particular case of Javascript code executed client side there are sometimes comments in the code that reveal the inner working of the server side application. Commenting code is not bad per se, but in this case it may give an attacker certain clues about how the backend system works or may describe certain bugs identified during testings for future fixes